# Modified version of Darboux's theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

Say we have a 4 dimensional real manifold and two 2-forms, called $k$ and $\omega$. Assume
$$
d k = 0, \hspace{1 cm} d \omega = 0.
$$
Furthermore, assume $\omega$ is non-degenderate, but $k$ is not. In particular, $k$ is rank-2, meaning there is a 2-dimensional vector space on which $k$ vanishes. Finally, assume
$$
k \wedge \omega = 0.
$$

My question is, is it possible to always find a set of local coordinates $(q_1, q_2, p_1, p_2)$ such that we simultaneously have,
$$
\omega = d q_1 \wedge d p_1 + d q_2 \wedge d p_2
$$
$$
k = d q_1 \wedge d q_2.
$$

Of course, if $k$ was not in the picture, this would just be Darboux's theorem. But here I am asking for a stronger statement.

Comment: Once you have $\omega$ of the desired form, write $k$ in these coordinates and see what $k\wedge\omega=0$ tells you,

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin I did attempt that but wasn't able to see any way to use that to prove the result. I am wondering if you have something in mind?

Comment: Are you sure your interpretation of rank 2 is correct?

Comment: It's possible I have used the language incorrectly, but I am correct in saying that $k$ is not non-degenerate and that at each point there is a dimension 2 subspace of the tangent space for which any element $v$ satisfies $k(v, \cdot ) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, the $4\times 4$ skew-symmetric matrix representing $k$ has rank $2$. So write $\omega = \phi_1\wedge \phi_2 + \phi_3\wedge  \phi_4$ and expand $k$ in terms of the $6$ basis elements.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have tried that but I think something further is needed. For instance, $k = f(q_1, q_2) d q_1 \wedge d q_2$ satisfies $d k = 0$ and $k \wedge \omega = 0$ for any function $f(q_1, q_2)$. In this example, some symplectomorphism would be needed to set $f$ to be $1$. From this example, I think many $k$'s can satisfy both $d k = 0$ and $k \wedge \omega = 0$, but some coordinate change is needed to set $k = d q_1 \wedge d q_2$ while preserving $\omega$

Comment: Ah, I was worrying only about the algebra of it. I don’t think you can get rid of such a coefficient function with the hypothesis you have.